# Объединение пути для .NET 2.0

Tags: c#, .net

Каким образом можно правильно описать метод для объединения пути к файлу?

Такое необходимо по той ситуации что стандартный `Path.Combine` в `.NET 2.0` не имеет перегрузок для передачи неограниченных параметров, т.е. в настоящее время, он принимает всего 2.

Я понимаю что я могу сделать свой метод, передавать в него `params string[]`

```
public static class Path
{
    public static string Combine(params string[] args)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        foreach (string pathPart in args)
        {
            result = System.IO.Path.Combine(result, pathPart);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

но мне кажется есть более изощренный способ.

Comment: `new[] { "aaa", "bb", "c" }.Aggregate("", Path.Combine)`

Comment: @MarkShevchenko: `.NET 2.0` использование linq и ему подобного не предвидится.

Comment: В наше время использовать .NET 2.0.... Жуть...

Comment: Кстати `Aggregate` из Linq можно заменить на [string.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), доступен с .NET 1.1

Comment: Делать все самому, через StringBuilder,  использовать для разделителя Path.DirectorySeparator.

Answer (score 2):

Мне удалось найти один изощренный способ в [этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/760707/1101913) на английском Stack Overflow. Суть его заключается в том, чтобы добавить [Extension Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) расширяющий System.String, который вызывает метод `Path.Combine`.

```
public static class StringExtensions {
  public static string CombineWith(this string path1, string path2) {
    return Path.Combine(path1, path2);
  }
}
```

Таким образом, передачу массива параметров можно будет осуществить путем цепочки вызовов:

```
string path = @"C:\test".CombineWith("one").CombineWith("two.txt");
```

Это решение будет работать при двух условиях:

1. Extension Methods поддерживаются в C# 3 и выше. Следовательно, необходимо иметь Visual Studio 2008 и выше.
2. Для компиляци Extension Method необходим `ExtensionAttribute`, которого нет в .NET Framework 2.0. К счастью, компилятор поддерживает "утиную типизацию", поэтому достаточно лишь объявить этот атрибут в своем проекте. Пример ниже взят [отсюда](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter1/Versions.aspx).

   ```
   namespace System.Runtime.CompilerServices {
     [AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets.Assembly | AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
     public class ExtensionAttribute : Attribute {
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: Не понятно только стало ли лучше (в плане читаемости и прочих качеств кода) чем было у автора. Сложнее и неочевиднее вот точно стало...